# How is the data being passed from java script to php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Okay, so I've been trying to learn web programming for a project that I need to submit soon.
Anyways, I've stumbled on a tutorial that I cannot, for the love of me, understand how does the data from his javascript is passed to the php script that he wrote.

Here's the snippet.

Javascript:

```
        $("form").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var name = $("#mail-name").val(); 
            var email = $("#mail-email").val(); 
            var gender = $("#mail-gender").val(); 
            var massage = $("#mail-massage").val(); 
            var submit = $("#mail-submit").val();  
            $(".form-message").load("mail.php",{
                name: name,
                email: email,
                gender: gender,
                massage: massage,
                submit: submit
            });
        })

    })
```

PHP:

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $massage = $_POST['massage'];

    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorEmail = false;

    if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($massage)) {
        echo "<span class='from-error'> Fill in all fields!</span>";
        $errorEmpty = true; 
    }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        echo "<span class='from-error'> Write a valid e-mail address!</span>";
        $errorEmail = true; 
    }else{
        echo "<span class='form-success'> E-mall has been sent! </span>";
    }
```

how is the php here able to receive the data from the "form"? Also, on the $("form") should this be either an ID or a CLASS set for the form that will contain the information (that wasn't mentioned in the tutorial).

Lastly, is the .load("mail.php") the one responsible for sending the data to php?

If so, why did he add $(".form-message") which is a p tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , the  `$("form")` reffer to the `<form>` html tag in your page.

So basicaly , `$("form").submit` reffer to an event form click(submit of the form).

The `.form-message` is a class of a div or p ... which will contain the response of the `mail.php`.In the example here it could be on of those lines :

```
<span class='from-error'> Fill in all fields!</span>
<span class='from-error'> Write a valid e-mail address!</span>
<span class='form-success'> E-mall has been sent! </span>
```

The load jquery function here is going to make an HTTP Request sending parameters to the mail.php file.

```
{
   name: name,
   email: email,
   gender: gender,
   massage: massage,
   submit: submit
}
```

The php file in going to map the given parameter as :

```
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $gender = $_POST['gender'];
 $massage = $_POST['massage'];
```

> Remember that parameters name should be kept the same.

Check out here some useful links about :

[JQuery load function](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

[PHP : variables from external sources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Comment: okay so it is the load function that is the one that is responsible for sending the data to php.
On the script, he also wrote on the load function the $(."form-message") I kinda get the part that this is the one that will "catch" what is needed to be displayed as response from the load but is it really necessary? Is there a different way to send the data to php using load function without inheriting it from an ID or a CLASS?

Comment: you can do an ajax call if you want otherwise

Comment: the .form-message is where the  response will be placed in the HTML page

Answer (score 0):

When you are submitting data from a form, with either GET or POST, it goes to the action parameter in that form which can be a php script.The .load() function gets the mail.php file with the parameters which you set in your javascript, and returns some html code which gets appended in your p tag ( the .form-message ).

So when you load it, and set those parameters, that's when the js is sending the data to the PHP.

$("form") means any form on the page. $("#form") is selecting the element with the ID form, and $(".form") is selecting the element with the class form.

Comment: Okay now that I get that part. The thing is, I don't need to append the data anywhere after I send it to the php file (which will also send the data to the backend) so is there a way for me to do this without having the need to append?

Comment: I don't think that having an empty <p> tag that has the data that is appended present on your code and leaving it there doing nothing is a good idea?

Comment: There are two ways of doing this without appending:
1. Don;t use javascript. Create a simple form, with an action and some inputs with the names that you are going to fetch in your PHP file, use an input type=submit to make the submit for the form, the php will do it's thing and return a page that you want

2. To do this asynchronously, implement JQuery and do an AJAX on button click which does something in a php script, and make it return either success or error and don't do anything with that data. Or just don't make it return anything..